# Does the Google Device Access API allow turning a camera on or off? Or turning notifications on or off?

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

Looking at the [Google Device Access API](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access), I don't see a command to turn a camera on or off. And I also don't see a command to turn notifications for a camera on or off. I see the camera traits [here](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/camera), but maybe there are commands somewhere else that apply to any type of device?

Am I missing it, or is this functionality in fact not provided?

I had hopes that I would be able to refine notifications based on smart home events, as opposed to a strict time schedule as it is now...

Answer (score 0):

Not what you were looking for, but you can query the on- or offline status: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/connectivity

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not at this time for Cameras.

Cameras Traits do not include connectivity - [link](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/camera)
Thermostat does list the Connectivity trait - [link](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/thermostat)